# line 5 root.["bg"] = 'red' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from tkinder import *

root = Tk()

root.["bg"] = 'red'
root.title('Ой!')
root.geometry('1000x900')

root.resizable(width=false, height=false)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Уберите точку перед квадратной скобкой.

Comment: попробуйте root.configure(background='red')

Comment: @Интик и так как в вопросе сработает (мои глаза...), если точку убрать и исправить еще 3 опечатки.

Comment: @insolor  почемуто в данном случае я за более длинное и более явное написание.хотя чаще лень сильнее

Comment: @Интик в данном случае полезнее указать на конкретную ошибку, чем предлагать замену.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root['bg'] = 'red'
root.title('Ой!')
root.geometry('1000x900')

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

root.mainloop()
```